# How to dynamically build a Hash dataset in Rails?

Tags: ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working to build a chartjs data object that contains a dynamic number of datasets. In my Ruby on Rails 5 controller, I'm trying the following:

```
chartJsObject = []

chartJsObject << {
  label: "Label Stuff",
  datasets: []
}

i = 0
num = 5

while i < num  do
  chartJsObject.datasets << [rand(10), rand(10)]
   i+=1
end
```

This is resulting in the following error:

```
undefined method `datasets' for [{:label=>"Label Stuff", :datasets=>[]}]:Array
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here to be able to loop through and populate chartJsObject.datasets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first line you define `chartJsObject` as an array:

```
chartJsObject = []
```

then in the second, you push a hash object in it:

```
chartJsObject << {
  label: "Label Stuff",
  datasets: []
} #=> [{:label=>"Label Stuff", :datasets=>[]}]
```

Now, what you have is an array of hash objects. In order to insert the data in `datasets` you just need access to the hash object, probably like so:

```
i = 0
num = 5

while i < num  do
  chartJsObject[i][:datasets] << [rand(10), rand(10)] if chartJsObject[i]
  i+=1
end
```

Comment: thanks but this seems to be overwriting the same dataset. It's looping 5 times but only returning one dataset. Not 5 within chartJsObject.datasets

Comment: Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: Because you might be writing datasets in only one hash instead of inserting another hash for different datasets